# How should I handle Keycloak users in my database?

Tags: angular, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, keycloak

I have no idea on how to use Keycloak with my app. I need to connect and sync it with my Postgres database. I am in process of making MVP (Minimum Viable Product). My database schema looks like this: [database diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMwBx.png). Attributes in this diagram can of course be changed.

So I have to connect Keycloak to User table. What attributes should I use from Keycloak user info? Should I even save users that sign in through Keycloak in my own database? If not, how should I handle it?

Teck stack for this app: Angular, Spring Boot, PostgreSQL

For now my Keycloak sign in works, anyone can log in. But can't see posts because they do not have permissions that is given to them using keycloak roles.

I didn't store any users in database until now. I started working and realized I do not know how to start.

Comment: Read this: [ask]

Comment: you can check for this tutorial. https://www.djamware.com/post/6225b66ba88c55c95abca0b6/spring-boot-security-postgresql-and-keycloak-rest-api-oauth2

Comment: Did you map Keycloak roles to Spring authorities (using `spring-boot-oauth2-resource-server`, not the deprecated keycloak adapters for Spring) ? If not, start there: https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials

Comment: Also, OAuth2 handling in your Angular app, have a close look at https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client